# No etched frame on TitledBorder for JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a `JPanel` on a `JFrame` and I have a **TitledBorder** on the `JPanel`.  I create the `JPanel` with the titled border in **NetBeans** and I can see my title and the etched frame.  When I run, I only see the title but not the etched frame.  Any idea why I can't see the etched frame?  I've tried setting the look and feel but can't get the frame to show up and it looks odd having the title with no border.

Running **Java 1.7** on **Windows 7**.  I don't recall this happening when we were using **java 1.6**.

Here's sample code:

```
package javaapplication1;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form NewJFrame */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));

    jLabel1.setText("This is just an etched frame");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(234, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("My Titled Border"));

    jTextField1.setText("Not on the titled border");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Where is the frame:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Ahhh, my good friend `GroupLayout`, how much I longed for you. Seriously though, you'll do better if you learn to write the GUI yourself and not with an editor.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer yet*

This is what I get in 1.7:

[image]

Is it not what you want?

**Edit:**

Try running this:

```
public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JLabel("AAAAA"));
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
        add(p);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new NewJFrame();
    }
}
```

It's very minimal and should narrow the options. This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: When I run it I don't see the border on the lower panel.

Comment: @Mike_G Clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: I did the clean and rebuild and I get the same behavior.  I've built the code with Netbeans and Eclipse and get the same results.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the Java version running on Windows 7.

Comment: I also see the expected result using `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`; maybe _not an answer yet_, but useful nonetheless.

Comment: I just ran the sample you posted and I don't see the border with the title.

Comment: @Mike_G Is it like that for all look-and-feels?

Comment: I tried the following look and feels and only the Nimbus shows the frame but that look and feel isn't what we want.

Comment: "javax.swing.plaf.metal.WindowsLookAndFeel", "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel", "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel", "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel", "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"

Comment: @Mike_G Do you have another machine with Java installed that you can run the code on (could be corrupted installation)? Maybe update it to the latest 1.7 version if it's not there already?

Comment: I tried running on my home machine that has java 1.7 and everything looks fine.  There must be something wrong with my Java 7 install :(

Comment: @Mike_G Well, at least you found what's wrong. Reinstalling Java is easy and quick. Hope it's just that.

Comment: @Mike_G Can you please post a solution or allow me to edit my answer with what you found? I would like an accepted solution for this question (you can accept your own solution).